# Cannot convert ISO8859-1 to cyrillic in ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have text **"ÐÐ¾ÑÑÐ¸Ð½Ð°Ñ"**, and I want to convert it to cyrillic.  2cyr.com says that this is ISO8859-1 format. I tried

```
"ÐÐ¾ÑÑÐ¸Ð½Ð°Ñ".force_encoding("ISO8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
```

But it returned => 
`"Ã\u0090Â\u0093Ã\u0090Â¾Ã\u0091Â\u0081Ã\u0091Â\u0082Ã\u0090Â¸Ã\u0090Â½Ã\u0090Â°Ã\u0091Â\u008F"`

What should I do to make the final word be **"Гостиная"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the other way round. Your string is the result of:

```
str = "Гостиная".force_encoding('ISO8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
#=> "Ð\u0093Ð¾Ñ\u0081Ñ\u0082Ð¸Ð½Ð°Ñ\u008F"

puts str
#=> ÐÐ¾ÑÑÐ¸Ð½Ð°Ñ
```

To revert it, use:

```
str.encode('ISO8859-1').force_encoding('UTF-8')
#=> "Гостиная"
```

Of course, this only works if the malformed string is left intact (it contains several invisible / unprintable characters).

Comment: it doesn't work for me. It returned "\xD0о\xD1\xD1ина\xD1"

Comment: @user3434212 this is due to StackOverflow's text processing, I've just updated my answer - please try again

Comment: it's worth noting that your original string is the result of a bug somewhere mis-interpreting encodings, it should never have happened.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is switch the order of methods:

```
puts "ÐÐ¾ÑÑÐ¸Ð½Ð°Ñ".encode("CP1252")
#=> �о��ина�
```

Your string still contains broken chars, but that is likely to be inherent to your original string. Online tools like [this one](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/) give the same result.

Comment: So you say, that it's impossible to get the original word, but 2cyr.com could encode it, isn't it?